# Performance of Open MPI: is there an accumulation of time in independent nodes?

Tags: performance, fortran, mpi

I'm developing a code in Fortran using Open MPI to accelerate my calculation.
The problem I notice is a bit confusing.

Here it is: I use each node in my cluster to calculate each portion of the same quantity. At first, I just let each node do the calculation and didn't perform any communication between nodes to see if I get the same amount of calculation time. And I did not...

This is what I get, the id=rank of the node together with the element number associated with. Moreover, I note that it is practically always the node of rank=number_machine-1 which is the fastest. Why do other nodes have a bigger time then ? Have you ever seen this problem ?
Thank you very much for your help.

- subprocs  id=  11 with   1014  elements done in..............  10.402s
- subprocs  id=   9 with    991  elements done in..............  12.749s
- subprocs  id=  10 with    991  elements done in..............  13.499s
- subprocs  id=   8 with    991  elements done in..............  21.416s
- subprocs  id=   7 with    991  elements done in..............  54.828s
- subprocs  id=   6 with    991  elements done in...........01m  16.038s
- subprocs  id=   5 with    991  elements done in...........03m  19.449s
- subprocs  id=   4 with    991  elements done in...........05m  25.459s

To Jérôme Richard:
In the cluster I'm using, there's only Open MPI and I'm not administrator to install other implementations, so I don't know if this problem also happens or not.

My algorithm is very basic: I have to calculate an array(1:N), I divide (1,N) into a number of sub-interval (i1,i2) equal to the number of nodes.

1. I allocate variables needed for each independent node.
2. I write a routine to calcule the quantity array(i1:i2) for each sub-interval (i1,i2). And I use the same routine for every nodes.
3. I just call mpirun and specify the number of nodes to be used.

Because I use the same routine for each node, I don't see how the calculation time could be different for all of the nodes.About the running environment, I use this version of Linux-3.2.91-server.

Comment: Is it only visible with OpenMPI and not other implementation? If not it is probably due to you algorithm. Can you describe it? Can you provide more details about the running environment?

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment, I have just edited my post to give some elements answering your questions.

Comment: A short program that shows the same issue of your code would really help here. But just checking the obvious - you have printed out i1 and i2 and checked they are correct? You have checked that the final values given by the code are correct? You have run it will all run time checks turned on?

Comment: Ian Bush: yes, I have checked the results and they are correct as I expect. Ok, I'm thinking about it too. I will try to reproduce the same problem with an other program.

Comment: you do not need to be root to install an other MPI implementation (e.g. you can install `mpich` in your user directory). when benchmarking, you should always ask exclusive access to the node, and you might also want to double check there is no process left over by other jobs/users.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your comments. I think I understand now why it is so. It has actually nothing to do with the MPI. The calculation time of different nodes shows the property of the quantity that I calculate, i.e. in my partition, the first, second and third intervals (i1,i2) which is (by convenience) always associated with nodes having rank=0,1,2 etc.. They contribute the most to my quantity and the other intervals contribute much less than them. This means I will have many zero or small numbers to operate with in the latter intervals. This is why I have an un-equilibrium in time among nodes.

I did yesterday an simple check where I force "the most rapid node" to calculate sequentially each portion (i1,i2), and I get the same kind of phenomenon.